# get addresses assigned by dhcp3-server

Tags: linux, dhcp

I use dhcp3-server to serve addresses to the 4 enet ports on my gigE card in my linux box.  The interfaces are eth1 to eth4 and are addressed 192.168.x.0 whefre x = 1,2,3,4.

How may I get dhcp3-server to tell me the addresses it has assigned and, if possible, the MACs of the devices it sees on one of those networks?

Comment: Check /var/log/messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dhcpd3 uses something called "leases" file where that information is stored, a common path is to find it as `/var/lib/dhcp3/dhclient.leases`.

Example output from this file:

```
lease 192.168.100.183 {
  starts 2 2012/01/17 17:52:37;
  ends 2 2012/01/17 18:02:37;
  binding state active;
  next binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 00:0c:29:79:ff:1b;
  client-hostname "ubuntubox";
```

}

Check manual page for the file at: http://linux.die.net/man/5/dhcpd.leases

Comment: Thanks!  I finally found the right man page and found this information also.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, any server program such as this would output this information to its log file, normally `/var/log/message/<service name>.log` or else `/var/log/<service name>/*.log`

I'm myself using dnsmasq, which gives messages like these:

```
gong dnsmasq[19510]: DHCPINFORM(eth1) 10.0.4.23 00:0c:29:0b:0e:15
```